# NetChart does not automatically rearrange nodes when using addData

Tags: javascript, zoomcharts

When we load our netchart, it displays a network where the user can then double-click on a node to expand the network further.

The original layout is fine - the chart fits the container perfectly (see netchart-original.png).  When the user double-clicks and loads the additional data (using `chart.addData()`), the chart zooms out (over a period of about 20 seconds) and the node spacing is not correct (see netchart-expanded.png).  We have called `updateSize`, `paintNow`, `resetLayout` and have even tried pausing before calling these functions but nothing seems to work.
Clicking on the "Rearrange Elements" toolbar button corrects the layout and node distancing and fits the chart within the container.
[image: netchart-original.png]
[image: netchart-expanded.png]

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use chart.zoom("overview") to reset the layout (use with a little timeout after adding the data).

however, this is not a normal scenario. please send sample js + data to support@zoomcharts.com for additional help or share a jsfiddle with anonymous data.

thanks,
Janis